# Test unique filtered index with tSQLt

Tags: sql-server, unit-testing, tsqlt

Currently I am trying to test the table that has unique filtered index. The only suggestions I've found so far is to use CONSTRAINT instead of index as `tSQLt` has `ApplyConstraint` SP. However I couldn't find anyway how to do filtered constraint... Any suggestions?

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[prime_rates]
(
    [prime_rate] DECIMAL(5, 3) NOT NULL
  , [start_date] DATE          NOT NULL
  , [end_date]   DATE          NOT NULL
        DEFAULT '12/31/2099'
);
GO

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX [UIX_prime_rates_end_date]
    ON [dbo].[prime_rates] ([end_date])
    WHERE [end_date] = '12/31/2099';
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [Test Class1].[test when 2 active prime rates are inserted then raise error]
AS
    BEGIN

        EXEC tSQLt.FakeTable @TableName = N'prime_rates';

        EXEC tSQLt.ApplyConstraint 'dbo.prime_rates', 'UIX_prime_rates_end_date';

        INSERT INTO dbo.prime_rates (   prime_rate
                                      , start_date
                                      , end_date
                                    )
        VALUES (   1            -- prime_rate - decimal(5, 3)
                 , GETDATE()    -- start_date - date
                 , '2099-12-31' -- end_date - date
               );

        EXEC tSQLt.ExpectException @ExpectedSeverity = 16;

        INSERT INTO dbo.prime_rates (   prime_rate
                                      , start_date
                                      , end_date
                                    )
        VALUES (   1            -- prime_rate - decimal(5, 3)
                 , GETDATE()    -- start_date - date
                 , '2099-12-31' -- end_date - date
               );
    END;
```

Comment: So what is your problem? Unique constraint always creates unique index behind the scenes, so if you create it directly it will do its work.

Comment: How to make unique constraint to be filtered then?

Comment: You did not understand me. I said, CREATE UNIQUE INDEX DIRECTLY

Comment: Your code already creates it. The only strange thing is that your key column is the same with what you are filtered on. What field is supposed to be unique?

Comment: It is done in the example code I provided. I created unique index directly. However in that case there is no constraint and I do not know how to test it with tSQLt then

Comment: My index means that there supposed to be only 1 record with end_date = '2099-12-31'. There could be duplicates on that column, but the value '2099-12-31' is supposed to be single

Comment: Uffa....It's not a CONSTRAINT that makes smth to be unique, but it's a UNIQUE INDEX to make smth unique

Comment: My question is not about "how to create unique index". My question is how to test it with tSQLt?

Comment: test it like this: insert [dbo].[prime_rates] (prime_rate, start_date) values(1, '20170101') and it will succed. then repeat it:insert [dbo].[prime_rates] (prime_rate, start_date) values(2, '20170102')
and this will fail

Comment: How is it related to tSQLt framework?

Comment: Why are you testing the functionality that a unique index throws an exception on duplicates anyway? You shouldn't be testing that product features work.

Comment: and how this one"However I couldn't find anyway how to do filtered constraint... Any suggestions?" is related to tSQLt framework? You asked how to make that value to be unique in that tabel, the answer is CREATE UNIQUE FILTERED INDEX. And how to test it -- test it any way you want

Comment: @MartinSmith I do not wish to test product feature. I am testing 2 things. The first is to test that I did not do any mistake and my index do the thing I am expecting to do. Another thing I am testing that this functionality will always remain the same even if the index is renamed, or modified in any other way. It might be redundant, but I am currently learning tSQLt and this is the issue I've got so far and would like to know if it is even possible to test this functionality with tSQLt in any way (it might be other than catching exception)

Comment: One way would be to not use `tSQLt.FakeTable` for this - just truncate `dbo.prime_rates` so it is guaranteed to not contain any rows at  the start and insert two rows directly into into it. It will get rolled back when the test finishes.

Comment: If your index will be dropped there will be no uniqueness at all. Independently from your testing

Comment: By the way, you should NEVER pass a date as a constant like this:  '12/31/2099'. Your code will breake if someone logins with the default language Russian, or English (not english_us). Try to do insert in your table from a session where `set language russian` was executed first. Pass it as '20991231' or '2099-12-31'

Comment: @sepupic: "If your index will be dropped there will be no uniqueness at all. Independently from your testing" --> bingo! and this case would be caught by the unit test!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you are testing that there are no inadvertent schema changes that have broken (removed/disabled/changed the predicate) your unique filtered index.

If you fake the table you then need to add the unique filtered index to the fake yourself which negates the point.

This should work.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [Test Class1].[test when 2 active prime rates are inserted then raise error]
AS
  BEGIN
      IF @@TRANCOUNT = 0
        THROW 50000, 'This must be run in a transaction and rolled back afterwards. Use "EXEC tSQLt.RunAll;" etc. Don''t run directly ', 1;


      TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.prime_rates;

      INSERT INTO dbo.prime_rates
                  (prime_rate,
                   start_date,
                   end_date)
      VALUES      ( 1 -- prime_rate - decimal(5, 3)
                    ,GETDATE() -- start_date - date
                    ,'2099-12-31' -- end_date - date
      );

      EXEC tSQLt.ExpectException @ExpectedSeverity = 16;

      INSERT INTO dbo.prime_rates
                  (prime_rate,
                   start_date,
                   end_date)
      VALUES      ( 1 -- prime_rate - decimal(5, 3)
                    ,GETDATE() -- start_date - date
                    ,'2099-12-31' -- end_date - date
      );
  END
```